# Using Retrofit with Moshi, how do you ignore specific Object properties when doing POST, PUT, or PATCH

Tags: java, json, salesforce, retrofit2, moshi

Much like the title states, I'm using Retrofit2 with Moshi and I'm in a situation where I need to get an object with the ID that it's assigned by the server, but when I want to POST a new object of that same time, I can't have the ID property in the POST or else the server will reject the call, because the server generates certain fields on the object when created or modified.

So, get instance of object that has ID == GOOD
Post **new** instance of object (leaving the ID field null, or if I could somehow ignore that field specifically when doing POST, PUT, PATCH that'd be even better) == BAD.

Does anyone have a workaround or solution for this? Or maybe I'm just doing something incorrectly?

Comment: To clarify, you want to deserialize into this field, but then you want the field to be ignored when serializing? How about separate model types for the two separate use cases?

Comment: @EricCochran That's the solution I came up with, but that solution is cumbersome as it then it doubles the amount of objects you have to manage. I was wondering if there were a better solution for this

Comment: Is copying the object without the id before the call not fisible?

Comment: Is copying the object without the id before the call not fisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out everyone!

For the fields that the API won't let you update, you can just make / keep their fields null when POST/PATCH - ing and it will go through!